# Setting an object value providing only the name of the xml attribute/element

Tags: java, jaxb

Is it possible to set an attribute/element value to a JAXB object using only the name of that property?

Example:

If I have a class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
public class Book {

  @XmlElement(name = "title")
  private String name;
  @XmlElement(name = "author")
  private String author;

  // setters and getters
}
```

Can I set the name without using its setter(`setName()`), but only knowing the xml element name? Which in this case is `"title"`. It could look like this:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);
Something s = context.create***();
s.setValueToObject(book, "title", "New name"); // should do the same like book.setName("New name")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**SETTING VALUES BY PROPERTY NAME**

You could use the `java.lang.reflect` APIs to set a value on your object.

```
package forum13952415;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class ReflectionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        setValueToObject(customer, "firstName", "Jane");
        setValueToObject(customer, "lastName", "Doe");

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

    private static void setValueToObject(Object object, String property, Object value) throws Exception {
        Class clazz = object.getClass();
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(property);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(object, value);
    }

}
```

---

**SETTING VALUES BY XPATH**

MOXy offers the ability to get/set values in a domain object by XPath.  Below is an example.

**Demo**

In the example below we need to dig down to the underlying MOXy implementation to get access to the `setValueByXPath` method.

```
package forum13952415;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBHelper;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        XMLContext xmlContext = JAXBHelper.unwrap(jc, XMLContext.class);

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        xmlContext.setValueByXPath(customer, "@id", null, 123);
        xmlContext.setValueByXPath(customer, "first-name/text()", null, "Jane");
        xmlContext.setValueByXPath(customer, "last-name/text()", null, "Doe");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer id="123">
   <first-name>Jane</first-name>
   <last-name>Doe</last-name>
</customer>
```

**Customer**

Below is a sample domain model.  I've used one where the XML names are different from the Java names.

```
package forum13952415;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    private int primaryKey;

    @XmlElement(name="first-name")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(name="last-name")
    private String lastName;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Comment: In your `reflect` example, the parameter `property` of `setValueToObject` is the name of the field. However, it would be useful to be attribute name from the annotation. But don't bother, because I know how to do it. I was only wondering if there was a way to do it using the JAXB library. I guess it has internally a method used exactly when it reads the xml input.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to provide them over its setters.

if your method

```
s.setValueToObject(book, "title", "New name"); // should do the same like book.setName("New name")
```

do the setter work for you. then it's also  correct

Comment: That method does not exist. I am asking if there is something similar implemented in the library. Otherwise I could search in the class for the annotations and would do them with reflection. But I wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: No there is nothing similar

Comment: The EclipseLink MOXy implementation of JAXB (JSR-222) offers a `setValueByXPath` method like @TrueSoft is looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13952834/383861

Comment: Ok. nice to know. But he doesn't want to add xpath. or?

Comment: First, I would like if it was in the default implementation, not a separate library. Then, not necessary xpath, since I have the exact object for the specified attribute/element.

Comment: @TrueSoft - I have updated my answer with how this could be done via the `java.lang.reflect` APIs in the JDK/JRE:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13952834/383861